# Changing variabe id to variable name coming from a different table

Tags: coldfusion, datatables

I have a CF function that I am using trying to change an id from a table to get the corresponding name from another query that is setting up my DataTable. When I try just the query giving an exact number it works properly but when I try to do the insert into the table to change the name it is not. Does anyone see any errors that might prevent this function from changing the id to the corresponding name?

What I have tried:

```
<cffunction name="getop_id" access="public" returntype="query"> 
 <cfargument name="op_id" required="yes" > 
 <cfquery name="spitOutop_id" datasource="tco_associates"> 
 SELECT assoc_name 
 FROM dbo.tco_associates 
 WHERE assoc_id= #arguments.op_id# 
 </cfquery> 
 <cfreturn spitOutop_id.assoc_name > 
 </cffunction>
```

Then on my table I am calling:

```
<td style="display:none;">#getop_id(op_id)#</td>
```

in the spot of

```
<td style="display:none;">#op_id#</td>
```

Full Table:

```
<table id="processing" class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
        <th><b>ITEM ID</b></th>
        <th style="display:none;"><b>DEALER ID</b></th>
        <th style="display:none;"><b>DATE RECEIVED</b></th>
        <th style="display:none;"><b>OP ID</b></th>
        <th><b>DUE DATE</b></th>
        <th><b>STATUS</b></th>
        <th style="display:none;"><b>LATE</b></th>
        <th style="display:none;"><b>CLOSED BY</b></th>
        <th style="display:none;"><b>RMKS</b></th>
        <th style="display:none;"><b>PROCESSING LOCATION</b></th>
        <th><b>QTY</b></th>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
   <cfoutput query="processTable">                     
    <tr>
        <td class="details-control"></td>
        <td class="LAlign">#id#</td>
        <td style="display:none;">#processTable.name#</td>
        <td style="display:none;">#dateFormat(processTable.Date_Received, 'mm/dd/yyyy')#</td>
        <td style="display:none;">#op_id#</td>
        <td>#dateFormat(processTable.Date_Due, 'mm/dd/yyyy')#</td>
        <td>#dateFormat(processTable.Date_Complete, 'mm/dd/yyyy')#</td>
        <td style="display:none;">#Completed_Late#</td>
        <td style="display:none;">#Closed_by#</td>
        <td style="display:none;">#Rmks#</td>
        <td style="display:none;">#Processing_Location#</td>
        <td class="CAlign">#Item_Count#</td>
    </tr>                      
   </cfoutput>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Function Setting Up Table:

```
<cffunction name="displayTable" access="public" returntype="query">
    <cfset var processTable = ''>
    <cfquery name="processTable">
        SELECT *
        FROM dbo.Dealer_Track_Work, dbo.Dealer_Track_Dealers
        WHERE dbo.Dealer_Track_Work.dealerID = dbo.Dealer_Track_Dealers.id      
    </cfquery>
    <cfreturn processTable>
</cffunction>
```

op_id comes from dbo.Dealer_Track_Work which should match assoc_id in dbo.tc_associates that contains the corresponding assoc_name

jQuery (incase its needed)

```
function format ( d ) {

    return 'Item ID: '+d.id+'<br>'+
           'Dealer: '+d.dealerID+'<br>'+
           'Date Received: '+d.Date_Received+'<br>'+
           'Checked In: '+d.op_id+'<br>'+
           'Date Due: '+d.Date_Due+'<br>'+
           'Date Complete: '+ ((d.Date_Complete) ? d.Date_Complete : 'N/A')+'<br>'+
           'Completed Late: '+ ((d.Completed_Late) ? d.Completed_Late : 'N/A')+'<br>'+
           'Completed By: '+ ((d.Closed_by) ? d.Closed_by : 'N/A')+'<br>'+
           'Remarks: '+ ((d.Rmks) ? d.Rmks : 'N/A')+'<br>'+
           'Location: '+d.Processing_Location+'<br>'+
           'Item Count: '+d.Item_Count+'<br>';
    }
// Setup the page once it has loaded.
$(document).ready(function() {
var oTable = $('#processing').DataTable( {
        "columns": [ 
            {
                "class":          "details-control",
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ""
            },
            { "data": "id" },
            { "data": "dealerID" },
            { "data": "Date_Received" },
            { "data": "op_id" },
            { "data": "Date_Due" },
            { 
              "data": "Date_Complete",
              "render": function(data){
              return ((data) ? "COMPLETED" : "PROCESSING");
              }
            },
            { "data": "Completed_Late" },
            { "data": "Closed_by" },
            { "data": "Rmks" },
            { "data": "Processing_Location" },
            { "data": "Item_Count" }
        ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']],
        "columnDefs": [
            { "targets": [0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11], "searchable": false }
        ],
        "sDom": '<"row view-filter"<"col-sm-12"<"pull-left"l><"pull-right"f><"clearfix">>>t<"row view-pager"<"col-sm-12"<"text-center"ip>>>',
        select: {
            style: 'single'
        },
        scrollY:        250,
        deferRender:    true,
        scroller:       true,
        /*"aLengthMenu": [[25, 50, 75, -1], [25, 50, 75, "All"]],
        "iDisplayLength": 25,*/
        "oLanguage": {
            "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ <label for='processing_length'><strong>records per page</strong></label>",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sPrevious": "«",
                "sNext": "»",
            }
        }
    });
```

[image]

Comment: You have been around S.O. long enough to know the drill ;-) Descriptions like "does not work not" are very ambiguous.  1) What is the *actual* result and what did you *expect* it to be instead? 2) Are you getting any error messages (if yes, post them)? 3) What is an example of the `#arguments.op_id#` value? 4) Did you troubleshoot and test the function with that sample value as an argument? If not, what happens when you do? ie `<cfset getop_id(op_id="the sample value")>`

Comment: Find out one of the id's that cause an error. Create a simple test page with only the function. Then call it inside a try catch: `<cftry><cfset getop_id(op_id="the sample value")><cfcatch><cfdump var="#cfcatch#"></cfcatch></cftry>`

Comment: Hold on a sec... You need to start reading the error messages ;-) Sometimes they lie, but this one tells you exactly what the problem is: *The value returned from the getop_id function is not of type query.*.  The function claims it returns a query object,  but you are actually returning a simple string instead ie `<cfreturn spitOutop_id.assoc_name >`. Change the `returntype` to indicate what type of value the function actually returns.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93556/discussion-between-leigh-and-vicki).

Comment: Leigh is spot on... you have a mismatched type. Leigh - add your answer to the Answer block.